LineageOS with automatic full disk backups?
Is it possible to set up LineageOS on a Smartphone in a way that it:

Can do OTA updates.
Doesn't lose root (Magisk) after every OTA update.
Can do full disk backups (E.g. using sth. like Open Recovery Script and store them on my local NAS.)

At the moment I notice that:

I have to use Lineage Recovery to use OTA updates.
I have to reflash Magisk after every OTA update to keep it rooted.
I can't to full disk backups from Lineage Recovery (especially not automatically).

(By full disk backup I mean a full backup of all device partitions that I can easily flash in one go. E.g. in case I accidentally delete important data or install a broken broken OTA update etc.)
I'm using LineageOS 21 with Lineage Recovery, Magisk, MicroG and F-Droid. Current device: OnePlus 5T.

Edit:
In order to not lose Magisk/root after every OTA update, I had to disable Update Recovery:
System -> Advanced -> Updater -> Preferences -> Disable Update Recovery
LineageOS apparently supports TWRP's OpenRecoveryScript for OTA updates and even worked for me when I had encryption enabled (which happens automatically when you set a lock like a pattern, password or pin).
Since OpenRecoveryScript is supported, it should be possible to automatically create full backups of all partitions like this:
backup.ors:
decrypt 'my_password'
backup SDCRBAE
reboot

(In case you have a pattern instead of PIN/Password, you need to translate it to the password as described on the bottom of this page.)
create_backup.sh:
if ls /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/*/* > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Warning, there are old backup(s) on your device. Creating a backup would contain the old backup(s). Press enter to continue anyway." && read
fi

cp ./backup.ors /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript
reboot recovery


On a rooted device a full dump of all partitions shouldn't be a problem, however encrypted user data (hardware backed) and the AndroidKeystore content which is hardware backed, too may be lost. This can happen even after a full recovery if the keys contained in the backup no longer match the required keys in the security hardware element. Not sure if Android updates those keys at all or even periodically (only by a factory reset they will change for sure)

@Robert Thanks for sharing that info. What if I temporarily remove the device encryption before triggering each backup?

Removing device encryption would require to rewrite every byte of your user data partition. I don't think that you want to do do that. But thinking about a backup plan it may be possible with root permissions to extract the master encryption key out of some process (I don't know the encryption system well enough to know if this is really possible) and include it in the backup. But the AndroidKeystore problem remains.

@Robert I made some discoveries and added a bit to my question. Do you think this could work? My hope is that by using the decrpyt command before running the backup command, the backup itself will contain the files unencrypted and that restoring would basically reencrypt them using the current devices key.

I guess the question would be if TWRP's backup command accesses the partition's data directly or if it uses the transparent decryption layer.

Modern devices use File Based Encryption, therefore the files are decryped on [file] access. I don't think there is a possibility to decrypt them when accessing the whole partition as block device (that is just a guess, I don't know any details about the used FBE implementation).

I just made an interesting discovery: NANDroid backups as produced by TWRP don't contain the data partition on a block device level. Instead if it's just a tar archive. Unfortunately a custom version of tar is required to do the extraction and there is no build available that works outside of TWRP, so I can't verify with certainty that it could be extracted without the hw backed keys. One way to verify would be to extract a backup of device A on device B.

Another unfortunate discovery is that rebooting into TWRP to autorun the openrecoveryscript always causes TWRP to ask for my lock pattern, even though my script starts with the decrypt command including the password. I wonder how OTA updates get around that. Maybe it's actually using the /cache/recovery/command interface and TWRP incorrectly displays Running openrecoveryscript.. when an OTA update is being installed.

OTA updates are applied on the unencrypted system partitions. That the user partition requires the PIN/pattern/password is normal as it is used to protect the encryption key. It is required to get the master encryption password from the security systemin the TEE https://security.stackexchange.com/q/256863/1204
